# EasyMock: isA() fails on the right class

Tags: java, easymock

I'm telling mock object to wait for method with command:
mockObject.registerSQLDriver(isA(SomeName.class));

At runtime method is called exactly with instance of SomeName class, but the test fails telling that "Unexpected method call registerSQLDriver()"

What can cause this problem?

Here is the code:

```
resetToDefault(_SQLDriverManager);
_SQLDriverManager.registerSQLDriver(isA(SQLDriver.class));
expectLastCall().anyTimes();
replay(_SQLDriverManager);
```

Comment: The error is at line 73, or 56, or perhaps 865. Without code, it's hard to say. Maybe you told your mock this method would be called once, whereas it's in fact called several times.

Comment: The error message says "Unexpected method call registerDriver()". You mocked the method "registerSQLDriver". Those are not the same methods.

Comment: Error message says exactly about registerSQLDriver(). It seems to me, that problem is not in isA(). I changed it to notNull() for example, it still fails.

Comment: The actual SQLDriverManager used by the tested code must be another mock than the one you configured. Are you sure you didn't configured a local _SQLDriverManager variable, and the code in fact uses an instance _SQLDriverManager variable?

Comment: You are right. Later I inisialised another instance of Mock. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you are mocking one instance and testing another instance.
To check this you should add a `name` parameter in the mock creation:

```
Comparable<String> mock01 = EasyMock.createMock("M1", Comparable.class);
Comparable<String> mock02 = EasyMock.createMock("M2", Comparable.class);

EasyMock.expect(mock01.compareTo(EasyMock.isA(String.class))).andReturn(1);
EasyMock.replay(mock01, mock02);

mock02.compareTo("Test");

EasyMock.verify(mock01, mock02);
```

In this case the test will fail with the message:

> Unexpected method call M2.compareTo("Test")

instead of:

> Unexpected method call Comparable.compareTo("Test")